# What are the possible values for the encoding in libxml2 -> HTMLparser.h -> htmlReadMemory

Tags: html, http, parsing, encoding, libxml2

I'm currently doing some iOS HTML parsing using Hpple but and want to provide the expected encoding for the HTML string but cannot find the possible values for the parameter. The Hpple library has a fuction:

```
+ (TFHpple *) hppleWithXMLData:(NSData *)theData encoding:(NSString *)theEncoding;
```

Which uses libxml2's [htmlReadMemory](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html#htmlReadMemory):

```
htmlDocPtr  htmlReadMemory(const char * buffer, 
                           int size, 
                           const char * URL, 
                           const char * encoding, 
                           int options);
```

Neither the function's documentation nor the libxml2's [encoding support documentation](http://xmlsoft.org/encoding.html) say anything about about the possible values and what is the default encoding used when no encoding (nil) is specified.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the configuration of your libxml2 build. If you build libxml2 with [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or ICU, you'll get all the encodings that these libraries supports. Without iconv or ICU, libxml2 has [native support](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/encoding.c) for:

```
UTF-8
UTF-16 UTF-16LE
UTF-16BE
ASCII US-ASCII
ISO-8859-1
ISO-8859-2
ISO-8859-3
ISO-8859-4
ISO-8859-5
ISO-8859-6
ISO-8859-7
ISO-8859-8
ISO-8859-9
ISO-8859-0
ISO-8859-11
ISO-8859-13
ISO-8859-14
ISO-8859-15
ISO-8859-16
```